# Huawei Map Kit, is there a way to define an onClick event on a marker cluster?

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery, huawei-map-kit

I am creating an app for AppGallery using Huawei Map Kit.
Map kit doesn't have a cluster manager, as Gmaps.
You can only make markers clusterable, but there doesn't seem to be any way of handling that clustering, especially the onClick event.

Does anyone know a way that I can menage the on cluster click event?
As of now, clicking on a cluster of markers procs a random marker click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may can refer this library:https://github.com/billtom20/3rd-maps-utils

CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity -> public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster cluster)